# k8s - what happens to persistent storage when cluster is deleted/?

Tags: kubernetes

Do they get permanently deleted as well? 
I imagine they do, since they are a part of a cluster, but I'm new to k8s and I can't find this info online.

If they do get deleted, what would be the preferred solution to keep the data for a cluster that sometimes gets completely deleted and re-deployed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation you can avoid complete PersistentVolume deletion by using retain reclaiming policies. 
In this case even after PersistentVolume deletion it still exist in external infrastructure, like AWS EBS. So it is possible to recover or reuse existed data.

You can find more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#retain) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/)